# Advanced Linear Algebra: Proving that a Basis of a vector space is linearly independent in its algebraic dual

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let E be a vector space with a basis $(x_j), j∈J $ and let E' be its algebraic dual (recall that E' is the vector space of all linear maps from E to the scalar field F).

For all $j ∈ J$, let $x^*_j ∈ E'$ be defined by:

If $j \neq k: x^*_j(x_k) = 0$.
If $j=k: x^*_j(x_k) = 1.$

Prove that $(x^*_j) ,(j∈J)$ is linearly independent in $E'$. Is it a base if $J$ is finite? What if $J$ is infinite?

I am having trouble working with the algebraic dual of a vector space. How do I go about proving this linear independence? And should I interpret the two questions that follow?

If you have any recommendations regarding my Latex notation, feel free to critique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the scalars scalars $\alpha_{j}, j \in J'$, where $J'$ is a finite subset of $J$, satisfy
$$
0 = \sum_{j \in J'} \alpha_{j} x^{*}_{j}. 
$$
Desired conclusion: each of the $\alpha$'s is zero.

The right-hand side of this equality is, again, an element of $E'$; i.e., is a linear functional on $E$, namely, the zero functional.  Acting with this functional on each $x_{k}$, we get
$$
0 = \sum_{j \in J'} \alpha_{j} x^{*}_{j} (x_{k}) = \alpha_{k},
$$
which gives the desired conclusion.

Comment: Why is the RHS an element of $E'$, how do you know it is a linear functional on E, namely the zero functional?

Comment: Because $E'$ is itself a vector space.  Consequently, a linear combination of elements of $E'$ is also an element of $E'$, hence is a linear functional on $E$.

It is the zero functional by hypothesis.  I am saying: IF $\sum_{j \in J'} \alpha_{j} x^{*}_{j}$ is the zero functional, THEN all the $\alpha$'s are zero.

Comment: I think, Halmos's "Linear Algebra Problem Book" would be a great help here.

Comment: Great, this makes sense. Thank you for your time. It does make sense then that $x^*_j$ for $j \in J$ is a base for finite $J$, but how would it be interpreted if $J$ is infinite?

Comment: @Pascal, if $J$ is infinite, you are asked only to verify the linear independence of the $x^{*}_{j}$'s.  This is because defining an "infinite basis" becomes tricky: linear independence is defined only for *finite* sets of vectors.  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Definition]